# Do CSS @media queries have any affect on a page load speed?

Tags: css, media

I wonder if there is any sense to try to reduce the number of `@media queries` in my CSS file

e.g. put all necessary code in one

`@media (max-width: 767px) { }`

query instead of writing it several times wherever I need it? Does it affect a page load speed anyhow?

Comment: Well, writing more `@media ...` blocks translates into more bytes in your stylesheet for the browser to download...

Comment: Only in the sense that writing the media query string several times will increase the size of your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

As some of the comments have stated, no, this will not affect the load speed of the page itself, only in the sense that the CSS file will be larger in file size with the more media queries you have, and therefor will require additional time to download.
Reducing your media queries down to one will also potentially limit the devices whose resolution is smaller and visiting the site/page, which is not at all optimal.